# Forwarding documents to Record Centre

Tags: metadata, records-center

I've created a record centre and defined a CT within it. Added the CT to Drop and Record library. So when a document is added to the drop box, fill in the metadata and submitted the document automatically is routed to the correct record library. great !

I now want to forward the document from a different  SC to the Record Centre.
I havent set any metadata on this library, I can forward the document using Send To but it will remain in the drop box as no supported metadata on this library.

Whats the best way to sent documents to a record centre from another SC ?

Is it usual to have the correct metadata specified upfront, that matches the record centre ?

Is there any advantage using a workflow to send the document ?

Just looking for any standardised way if there is such a thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into Central Administration, click General Application Settings then 'Configure Send to Connections'.

Give your connection a name, and under URL, you need to paste a special link.

To get this link, go to your Records Centre, click on Site Settings and then Content Organizer Settings. Scroll to the bottom of the page and you will find a link which looks something like this: http://site/subsite/_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx

Copy your link and paste it under Send-To-URL. Also allow manual submission from the Send to Menu. Click Add Connection and OK.

Run the Content Organizer Processing job for both the source and target site collections by going to Monitoring, Review Timer Jobs.

Test by going to a document in the source site collection and click the drop-down to Send to your Records Centre.

Should work. Probably won't. It'll be fun. Good luck.

This guide is good too: http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2011/06/configure-a-send-to-connection-to-a-records-center/